# Angular 1.x Browserify Jasmine how to set up code coverage test?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, browserify, karma-coverage

I am using Angular (1.x) with Browserify, and Jasmine as test framework. I would like to run code coverage test. I researched online and it's a little here and there and some of the examples doesn't work. I was wondering if any people have the experience setting the code coverage test for angular+browserify+jasmine ? and if there's a repo in github i can reference?

Answer (score 0):

Use karma-coverage. Check out my karma playground here: https://github.com/marcinmierzejewski1024/jasmine-karma-playground. It's propably based on istanbul(generated reports looks very similar) but I am not 100% sure